# google sheets regular expressions with grouping and repetition

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Hopefully somebody can help me with this regular expression.
I have following text:

```
xxx sku: AA123 xxx sku: BB345 xxx sku: CC678
```

and want to get the values: AA123 BB345 CC678 (thus without sku)

xxx = variable text with comma's and spaces included.
The number of sku's is minimal 1 and no maximum.

How can i arrange this with google sheets.

I made this myself for one:

```
sku: ([A-Z]+[0-9]+)
```

for two i have:

```
sku: ([A-Z]+[0-9]+).*sku: ([A-Z]+[0-9]+)
```

I think it is handy to use {1,}, but i don't know how.....

EDIT: There are some solutions provided with global modifier. Thank you for these suggestions. But i cannot use them because the REGEXEXTRACT from Google Sheets doesn't support the global modifier.

The REGEXREPLACE function supports the global modifier, but then i need an "inversed" regular expression.

Can somebody can help me with this problem, because i can't figured it out. Thanks in advance.....

Comment: U may use this `sku: ([A-Z]+[0-9]+)` for all. JUst enable g modifier.

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: g modifier is not possible, i'am using google sheets. see https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-capturing group for the `sku:` prefix and use a global modifier

```
(?:sku: )[A-Z0-9]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZ2gT1/1)

Comment: Thank you, it looks like a clean solution, google sheets doesn't support global modifier. See https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have that text in A1, this may work in a google sheet:

=JOIN(char(9), filter(split(A1, " sku: "), regexmatch(split(A1, " sku: "), "[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}")))

or use [A-Z][0-9]+ for the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\w+ sku:","")

this will return the three sku's with a space in between each, if you wish to split the values into separate cells in the same row, then leave the colon in there and use that as a delimiter in a split function like this:

=split(REGEXREPLACE(A10,"\w+ sku",""),":")